# Swift: How to check for base class and superclass on a subclass

Tags: swift

Why is following `is` check false?

```
class Person : BaseClass { ... }
class Parent : Person { ... }
.
.
let parent = Parent()
print("parent is BaseClass: \(parent.self is BaseClass)")
// this prints 'parent is BaseClass: false'
```

And how can I check the subclass its base class or superclass? Especially if I don't know how deep the object has been subclassed.

UPDATE:
My mistake the following is true

```
print("parent is BaseClass: \(parent.self is BaseClass)")
// this prints 'parent is BaseClass: true'
```

But this one is not

```
class GenericClass<T: BaseClass> { }
.
let myGeneric = GenericClass<Parent>()
print("myGeneric is GenericClass<BaseClass>: \(myGeneric.self is GenericClass<BaseClass>)")
// this prints 'myGeneric is GenericClass<BaseClass>: false'
```

In Playground I'm getting following warning:

> Playground.playground: Cast from 'GenericClass' to
>   unrelated type 'GenericClass' always fails

So how can I check for the generic relation to the base class?

Comment: This feels like an inappropriate use of generics... What problem are you trying to solve that causes you to think you need to do this?

Comment: Well it's simple. I need to do something with GenericClass<BaseClass> and all its subclasses. On run time I don't know the class of an object I can manage. So I need to check for it to be able to do the correct stuff with it. But it sounds to me as Swift is unable to check for the generic inheritance. It should be no problem also in compile time. What brings me to the idea to extend the 'is' operator.

Comment: Can you show me a sub-class of `GenericClass<BaseClass>`? Because you don't have any in your example.

Comment: Sorry I meant subclasses of the generic type like GenericClass<Parent>.

Comment: There is no class hierarchy among the various `GenericClass` types. None are sub-types of any of the others. In other words `GenericClass<Parent>` is *not* a subclass of `GenericClass<BaseClass>`. You *might* be able to do it if you expose the contained type as a `typealias`... Mess with that idea for a bit and I'll do the same.

Comment: Hm ok. Funny is in playground this `myGeneric is GenericClass` is true but in the project code there must be some generic... playground bug? I will try it somehow with the `typealias`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose the contained type as a typealias. Here is the solution.

```
protocol BaseClass { }
class Person : BaseClass { }
class Parent : Person { }

class GenericClass<T: BaseClass> {
    typealias Contained = T
}

let myGeneric = GenericClass<Parent>()
print("myGeneric is GenericClass<BaseClass>: \(type(of: myGeneric).Contained() is BaseClass)")
```

Comment: Ok this is working because the type of `myGeneric` is known at compile time. What about attributes in mirrored objects? If I will iterate over all attributes the type of them at compile time is `Any` but stuff like `attr.value is BaseClass` will work anyway. However the `type(of: myGeneric).Contained()` will not work because at compile time Any has no member like `Contained` of course. So how can we check the generic type at run time if at compile time we don't know the "real" type at all?

Comment: It sounds like you need a primer on how to use protocols. I suggest you do some research into them.

Comment: Ok I think I have did not make my point clearly. My apology. I will try again. I'm iterating over attributes of a mirrored object. All its attribute types are at compile time known as `Any`. One of them I expect to be the `GenericClass<BaseClass>` or some of the subclasses of the `BaseClass` like `GenericClass<Parent>`. My `BaseClass` is not a protocol, it's just what's called: base class. In this situation I just cannot call the Contained() constructor because `Any` has no such thing. I'm getting compiler error as expected. Is there any possibility to check for the generic type in this case?

Comment: Your array of `Any` objects is not really an array of *absolutely* anything. It is an array of a limited number of types. Those types must all conform to the same protocol. Maybe if you show more code I can help you.

Comment: But in your solution BaseClass as protocol does not require the `typealias Contained` this just implements the `GenericClass<T: BaseClass>`. So what's the point of the protocol here at all? But I think I know what you meant. If the requirement would be in the protocol, then it might be ok for the compiler. I will try it this way.

Comment: My solution above doesn't require reflection at all. Note that the compiler warns that the `is` will always return true. The `is` is unnecessary. If you want dyanamicism, you will need a protocol.

Comment: I know it does not require the reflection. But I'm using it in other content and need to do this generic check in the reflection.

Comment: You can't use it in the context you want to use it in. You have to use a protocol. I suggest you read up a bit on protocols and then post a new question that presents the actual problem you are having instead of this.

Comment: You are right about the context. In the reflection this is not working but it's the solution for my question here. Therefore accepted. Thank you.